# Windows Program Removal

Tags: windows-10

I need to make a script that can automatically remove software from a Windows machine, I'm thinking of using something with `product where name="" call uninstall` but I wanted to know if this will work with all/any programs on Windows I'd want to remove like AngryIPScanner or programs like Nmap. If this won't work for those is there a better way to go with getting rid of them automatically from systems?

Comment: I'm thinking of using something with `product where name="" call uninstall` .. using *what* exactly?  If these programs generally don't change, you can look under the GUID subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.  Each key will have a `Display Name` string and an `Uninstall String` string.  You can simply run the uninstall strings to uninstall products (via batch file if you like).

Comment: Would this https://pastebin.com/PK0fEUMC help as a starting point?  Avoid WMI and Win32_Product class like the plague.